# apt --fix-broken install fails

Tags: apt, raspberry-pi, raspbian, mono

I wanted to upgrade my packages on my raspberry pi, so I've successfully done a `apt-get upgrade`.

After that, I obviously wanted to do an `apt-get upgrade` but I had an error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-devel : Depends: ca-certificates-mono (= 6.0.0.319-0xamarin1+raspbian9b1) but 5.12.0.226-0xamarin3+raspbian9b1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Like it's recommanded, I did an `apt --fix-broken install`, but I've got a bunch of errors because of that.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libmono-system-runtime-interopservices-runtimeinformation4.0-cil libnunit-cil-dev libnunit-console-runner2.6.3-cil libnunit-core-interfaces2.6.3-cil libnunit-core2.6.3-cil libnunit-framework2.6.3-cil libnunit-mocks2.6.3-cil
  libnunit-util2.6.3-cil libpng12-0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-mono
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ca-certificates-mono
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 89 not upgraded.
171 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/31.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,144 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Reading changelogs... Done
Setting up mono-gac (6.0.0.319-0xamarin1+raspbian9b1) ...
* Installing 1 assembly from libnunit-console-runner2.6.3-cil into Mono

Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
E: installing Assembly /usr/lib/cli/nunit-console-runner-2.6.3/nunit-console-runner.dll failed
E: Installation of libnunit-console-runner2.6.3-cil with /usr/share/cli-common/runtimes.d/mono failed
* Installing 1 assembly from libnunit-core2.6.3-cil into Mono

Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
E: installing Assembly /usr/lib/cli/nunit.core-2.6.3/nunit.core.dll failed
E: Installation of libnunit-core2.6.3-cil with /usr/share/cli-common/runtimes.d/mono failed
* Installing 1 assembly from libnunit-core-interfaces2.6.3-cil into Mono

Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
E: installing Assembly /usr/lib/cli/nunit.core.interfaces-2.6.3/nunit.core.interfaces.dll failed
E: Installation of libnunit-core-interfaces2.6.3-cil with /usr/share/cli-common/runtimes.d/mono failed
* Installing 1 assembly from libnunit-framework2.6.3-cil into Mono

Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
E: installing Assembly /usr/lib/cli/nunit.framework-2.6.3/nunit.framework.dll failed
E: Installation of libnunit-framework2.6.3-cil with /usr/share/cli-common/runtimes.d/mono failed
* Installing 1 assembly from libnunit-mocks2.6.3-cil into Mono

Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
E: installing Assembly /usr/lib/cli/nunit.mocks-2.6.3/nunit.mocks.dll failed
E: Installation of libnunit-mocks2.6.3-cil with /usr/share/cli-common/runtimes.d/mono failed
* Installing 1 assembly from libnunit-util2.6.3-cil into Mono

Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
E: installing Assembly /usr/lib/cli/nunit.util-2.6.3/nunit.util.dll failed
E: Installation of libnunit-util2.6.3-cil with /usr/share/cli-common/runtimes.d/mono failed
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.nunit-console-runner into Mono

Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
E: installing Assembly /usr/share/cli-common/policies.d/libnunit-console-runner2.6.3-cil/policy.2.6.nunit-console-runner.dll failed
E: Installation of policy.2.6.nunit-console-runner with /usr/share/cli-common/runtimes.d/mono failed
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.nunit.core into Mono

Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
E: installing Assembly /usr/share/cli-common/policies.d/libnunit-core2.6.3-cil/policy.2.6.nunit.core.dll failed
E: Installation of policy.2.6.nunit.core with /usr/share/cli-common/runtimes.d/mono failed
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.nunit.core.interfaces into Mono

Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
E: installing Assembly /usr/share/cli-common/policies.d/libnunit-core-interfaces2.6.3-cil/policy.2.6.nunit.core.interfaces.dll failed
E: Installation of policy.2.6.nunit.core.interfaces with /usr/share/cli-common/runtimes.d/mono failed
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.nunit.framework into Mono

Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
E: installing Assembly /usr/share/cli-common/policies.d/libnunit-framework2.6.3-cil/policy.2.6.nunit.framework.dll failed
E: Installation of policy.2.6.nunit.framework with /usr/share/cli-common/runtimes.d/mono failed
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.nunit.mocks into Mono

Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
E: installing Assembly /usr/share/cli-common/policies.d/libnunit-mocks2.6.3-cil/policy.2.6.nunit.mocks.dll failed
E: Installation of policy.2.6.nunit.mocks with /usr/share/cli-common/runtimes.d/mono failed
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.nunit.util into Mono

Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in <15c986724bdc480293909469513cfdb3>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in <037438e7c61a4834974bb2bb24951222>:0
E: installing Assembly /usr/share/cli-common/policies.d/libnunit-util2.6.3-cil/policy.2.6.nunit.util.dll failed
E: Installation of policy.2.6.nunit.util with /usr/share/cli-common/runtimes.d/mono failed
dpkg: error processing package mono-gac (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 29
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mono-runtime-common:
 mono-runtime-common depends on mono-gac (= 6.0.0.319-0xamarin1+raspbian9b1); however:
  Package mono-gac is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mono-runtime-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mono-gac
 mono-runtime-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It's also recommanded to do an `apt --fix-broken install` when I do a `apt autoremove`.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-devel : Depends: ca-certificates-mono (= 6.0.0.319-0xamarin1+raspbian9b1) but 5.12.0.226-0xamarin3+raspbian9b1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem today and this worked for me (I'm running Armbian on a Pine64):

`mv /etc/mono/config.dpkg-new /etc/mono/config`

followed by

`apt install ca-certificates-mono`

I got the solution from [over here](https://serverfault.com/questions/976201/how-to-upgrade-ca-certificates-mono-if-4-8-1-0-0-version-is-already-installed):

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked !